# What is the order of calling destructors for temporaries in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor, temporary, object-lifetime

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  ~A() { std::cout << "~A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B {
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B" << std::endl; }
};

struct C {
  ~C() { std::cout << "~C" << std::endl; }

  void operator<<(const B &) {}
};

C f(const A &a = A()) {
  return C();
}

int main() {
  f(A()) << B();
}
```

Compiling with GCC and running gives the following output:

```
~C
~A
~B
```

Is it guaranteed that the destructors for temporary objects of types A, B and C will be called in this order when compiled with other compilers? In general, what is the order of destructor calls for temporaries if there is any?

Comment: What optimisation settings are you using? `~C()` should be called twice here unless RVO kicks is, no?

Comment: @aleguna: I'm using the defaults. It's -O0 I think.

Comment: @aleguna: gcc does copy elision even with no optimization enabled. You can disable it with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's talk about subexpressions and their sequencing. If `E1` is *sequenced before* `E2`, that means `E1` must be fully evaluated before `E2` is. If `E1` is *unsequenced with* `E2`, that means `E1` and `E2` may be evaluated in any order.

For `f(A()) << B()`, which is in your case the same as `f(A()).operator<<(B())`, we know that:

- `A()` is sequenced before `f(...)`,
- `f(...)` is sequenced before `operator<<` and
- `B()` is sequenced before `operator<<`

This also tells us that:

- `A()` is sequenced before `operator<<`
- `A()` is unsequenced with `B()`
- `f(...)` is unsequenced with `B()`

If we assume RVO, so as not to complicate things, the possible order a compiler could evaluate the subexpressions in are:

- `A()` -> `f(...)` -> `B()`, yielding `~B()` -> `~C()` -> `~A()`
- `A()` -> `B()` -> `f(...)`, yielding `~C()` -> `~B()` -> `~A()`
- `B()` -> `A()` -> `f(...)`, yielding `~C()` -> `~A()` -> `~B()`

The latter is the order observed in the OP. Note that the order of destruction is always the reverse order of construction.

Comment: Isn't `A()->B()->f(...)` also possible?

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. Is it guaranteed by the standard that the order of destructor calls opposite to the order of evaluation?

Comment: @vitaut: The order of destructor calls is always in the opposite order of construction. Gonna edit that part in.

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of expression `f(A()) << B();` is not specified. Thus, the order of construction/destruction is not specified as well.

Comment: That's what I thought at the very beginning, but I'm not sure it's correct.. I mean - to call `operator<<`, `C` must have been already defined (as `operator<<` is member of C). That would mean, that `f(A())` must be evaluated before calling `operator<<`. This means: 1-create `A`; 2-execute `f(A)`; 3. pass `B` as argument. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kiril C must have already been defined, but that happens at compile time ;v) . At runtime, it doesn't matter whether the object of type C is created before or after the other argument to the function.

Comment: As far as I understand the order of evaluation of A() and B() is undefined, but what about the object C? It is returned from a function so shouldn't it be constructed after the arguments? Also is the order of destruction opposite to the order of construction for temporaries?

Comment: Note that the order is not *undefined*, it's merely *unspecified* for the *most* part - it's necessary that `A()` is evaluated before `f(...)`, for example. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of operands of `<<` is unspecified. Hence, order is not guaranteed. Only the short-circuiting operators `&&`, `||`, the ternary operator `?:`, and the comma `,` operator has well-defined order of evaluation of operands. For others, it is not necessary that the left operand has to be evaluated before the right operand (or vice-versa).

Further, do not confuse operator precedence or associativity with order of evaluation. For a given expression `E1 op E2`, it is only necessary that before the operator `op` is applied, both `E1` and `E2` should be evaluated, but between themselves, `E1` and `E2` could be evaluated in any order.

Precedence rules decide the order in which operators are applied when there's more than 1 operator in an expression, such as `E1 op1 E2 op2 E3`.

Associativity is used to decide which operands bind to which operator, when the same operator is used more than once, that is, in `E1 op E2 op E3`, whether it is interpreted as `(E1 op E2) op E3` or `E1 op (E2 op E3)`.

Comment: Does it apply to overloaded operator, as well? What if I changed "<<" to ",", would it guarantee the order?

Comment: You cannot change the operator like that through overloading. Also, like I said, both operands have to be evaluated before the operator is applied. Your overloaded operator code will not be invoked until the operands are evaluated.